# MySQL LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE syntax error in path name

Tags: mysql, csv, syntax, upload, syntax-error

So I have a built a table and now need to upload a CSV.  But I am getting a syntax error.  I am new to a MariaDB server and HeidiSQL.  Any help greatly appreciated.  As I understand it HeidiSQL is basiclly the same as MySQL.

"   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE  'C:/Users/aline.kasliner/Desktop/MyStuff/Mullenserverw' at line 4 */
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 0 of 1 query: 0.000 sec. */   "

```
    LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE  'C:/Users/aline.kasliner/Desktop/MyStuff/Mullenserverwork/DisplayMediaData.csv'
    INTO TABLE Duke_Display_Media_Data
    OPTIONALLY FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
    ignore 1 rows
    (date_
    ,campaign 
    ,site  );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation the `[LOCAL]` part refers to an *optional* directive. The square brackets are not present in the final command, they're just the notation for indicating that part may or may not be present.

The command should be:

```
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...
```

When you see notation like `X [A|B|C] Y` that means one of A, B or C may be present, or they can be omitted altogether. Likewise, `X [A] [B] [C] Y` means that any of A, B, or C can be included, but they should be in that order, so `X A B Y` is valid, but `X C A A Y` is not.

Comment: I pulled the [] brackets off no luck